# Json extraction of specfic field via Python

Tags: python, json

Trying to get the "externalCode" field from the below incomplete json file, however i am lost, i used python to only get to second element and get the error. I am not sure how to go about traversing through a nested JSON as such below

```
 output.writerow([row['benefitCategories'], row['benefitValueSets']] + row['disabled'].values())
```

KeyError: 'benefitValueSets'

```
import csv, json, sys

input = open('C:/Users/kk/Downloads/foo.js', 'r')
data = json.load(input)
input.close()

 output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

 output.writerow(data[0].keys())  # header row

 for row in data:
     output.writerow([row['benefitCategories'], row['benefitValueSets']] +          row['disabled'].values())
```

Json file

```
[
 {
"benefitCategories": [
  {
    "benefits": [
      {
        "benefitCode": "NutritionLabel",
        "benefitCustomAttributeSets": [

        ],
        "benefitValueSets": [
          {
            "benefitValues": [
              null
            ],
            "costDifferential": 0,
            "default": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "displayValue": "$500",
            "externalCode": null,
            "id": null,
            "internalCode": "$500",
            "selected": false,
            "sortOrder": 0
          }
        ],
        "configurable": false,
        "displayName": "DEDUCTIBLE",
        "displayType": null,
        "externalCode": "IndividualInNetdeductibleAmount",
        "id": null,
        "key": "IndividualInNetdeductibleAmount",
        "productBenefitRangeValue": null,
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "values": [
          {
            "code": null,
            "description": null,
            "id": null,
            "numericValue": null,
            "selected": false,
            "value": "$500"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "benefitCode": "NutritionLabel",
        "benefitCustomAttributeSets": [

        ],
        "benefitValueSets": [
          {
            "benefitValues": [
              null
            ],
            "costDifferential": 0,
            "default": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "displayValue": "100%",
            "externalCode": null,
            "id": null,
            "internalCode": "100%",
            "selected": false,
            "sortOrder": 0
          }
        ],
        "configurable": false,
        "displayName": "COINSURANCE",
        "displayType": null,
        "externalCode": "PhysicianOfficeInNetCoInsurancePct",
        "id": null,
        "key": "PhysicianOfficeInNetCoInsurancePct",
        "productBenefitRangeValue": null,
        "sortOrder": 0,
        "values": [
          {
            "code": null,
            "description": null,
            "id": null,
            "numericValue": null,
            "selected": false,
            "value": "100%"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
```

Comment: Are you looking to fetch the null externalCode values inside 'benefitValuesSets', or the value set for each benefits element inside that json (eg. IndividualInNetdeductibleAmount, PhysicianOfficeInNetCoInsurancePct)?

Apologies if that's a silly question, but it wasn't clear from your initial post.

Comment: @kevinpowe where value set for each benefits inside that json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're looking to do with your code. There are multiple externalCode values for each element in the array, at least from the sample you've posted. But you can get the data you're looking for with this syntax:

```
data[0]["benefitCategories"][0]["benefits"][0]["externalCode"]
data[0]["benefitCategories"][0]["benefits"][1]["externalCode"]
```

The code below iterates through the data you're interested in (with a slightly modified JSON file so that it's complete) and works as desired:

```
import csv, json, sys

input = open('junk.json', 'r')
data = json.load(input)
input.close()

for x in data[0]["benefitCategories"][0]["benefits"]:
    print x["externalCode"] + "\n\n"
```

Comment: how do i get the second "externalCode", first one is great but need the 2nd one

Comment: As per the examples above, you'd use row['benefitCategories'][0]['benefits'][1]['externalCode'] in your code to fetch 'PhysicianOfficeInNetCoInsurancePct'

Comment: I got that but what about the "externalCode" that has null values, i am just totally confused about the standard for accesing and writing the syntax for json collection

Comment: At the point that you're trying to deal with the data, @purple_rein, you're dealing with a basic Python structure - a combination of arrays and dictionaries.

The basic rule of thumb you can use (and the examples you've got for accessing specific data should help here) is any map/dictionary in the JSON data gets turned into a dictionary in the corresponding Python structure, and any repeating element gets turned into an array.

Past that, it's a matter of eyeballing the data and walking through the structure you can see.

Doing a 'print data' may help you understand that structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import csv, json, sys

input = open('C:/Users/spolireddy/Downloads/foo.js', 'r')
data = json.load(input)
input.close()

 output = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

 output.writerow(data[0].keys())  # header row

 for row in data:
     output.writerow([row['benefitCategories'], row['benefitCategories'][0]['benefits'][0]['benefitValueSets'][0], row['benefitCategories'][0]['benefits'][0]['benefitValueSets'][0]['disabled']])
      # for externalCode:
      row['benefitCategories'][0]['benefits'][0]['benefitValueSets'][0]['externalCode']
```

Comment: This is for disabled, and it is bool so it wont have values. What about for "externalCode"